# MUI Permanent Drawer contained within sub div

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to figure out a way to make the MUI drawer be contained within a sub div. It seems that it simply overlaps on whatever content there is underneath it. This is an example I ported on codesanbox

[image]

How can I make so that the drawer is contained under the red header and the text content automatically have the right 'padding'?

[image: Edit mini-drawer-contained]

Comment: For some reason, the code sandbox link is broken.  Do you happen to have a copy of the code or another CodeSandbox link?

Comment: sorry it wasn't public. Now it should work (the same link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found a semi-elegant way of handling this: making the content of the drawer a "child" of the `MiniDrawer` component.

[StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-7hsmim?file=src%2FApp.tsx)

To get this working, you will need to refactor the `MiniDrawer` component to accept and render the `children` prop right after the drawer in the DOM.  Note also I added a margin to the top of the drawer to allow room for the red app bar:

```js
export default function MiniDrawer({ children }) {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const toggleMenuOpen = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: "flex", position: "absolute", height: "50%" }}>
      <Drawer variant="permanent" open={open} sx={{ height: "50%" }}>
        <DrawerHeader>
          <IconButton onClick={toggleMenuOpen}>
            {open ? <ChevronLeftIcon /> : <MenuIcon />}
          </IconButton>
        </DrawerHeader>

        <Divider />
        <List>
          {["Inbox", "Starred", "Send email", "Drafts"].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem key={text} disablePadding sx={{ display: "block" }}>
              <ListItemButton
                sx={{
                  minHeight: 48,
                  justifyContent: open ? "initial" : "center",
                  px: 2.5,
                }}
              >
                <ListItemIcon
                  sx={{
                    minWidth: 0,
                    mr: open ? 3 : "auto",
                    justifyContent: "center",
                  }}
                >
                  {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={text} sx={{ opacity: open ? 1 : 0 }} />
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {["All mail", "Trash", "Spam"].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem key={text} disablePadding sx={{ display: "block" }}>
              <ListItemButton
                sx={{
                  minHeight: 48,
                  justifyContent: open ? "initial" : "center",
                  px: 2.5,
                }}
              >
                <ListItemIcon
                  sx={{
                    minWidth: 0,
                    mr: open ? 3 : "auto",
                    justifyContent: "center",
                  }}
                >
                  {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={text} sx={{ opacity: open ? 1 : 0 }} />
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </Drawer>
      {children}
    </Box>
  );
}
```

The parent component that uses `MiniDrawer` would then simply pass whatever content you want to render as a child of the component like this:

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Box>
      <Box sx={{ backgroundColor: "red", height: 50 }} />
      <div className="App">
        <MiniDrawer>
          <div>
            <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
            <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          </div>
        </MiniDrawer>
      </div>
    </Box>
  );
}
```